# How do I respond to incoming network messages in a way that achieves loose coupling?

Tags: architecture

I'm working on a client-server sort of protocol right now in Ruby. I've hit a snag where I'm not entirely sure how to proceed. Currently, I have a class, `Remote` that signifies a remote connection (for use through EventMachine). When `Remote` receives a message (i.e, network packet), it sends it off to the `MessageDecoder`, which returns the decoded message in a hash, like so (pseudo-code ahead)

```
{ source = <the_remote_connection>,
  message_code = 1, // An operation code that indicates how to respond to this message
  payload = {
    packet_specific_key = packet_specific_value // provided by the decoder
  }
}
```

So, when I get this back from `MessageDecoder`, the `Remote` ships it off to its `ConnectionListener`, which needs to decide how to distribute that message across the application. Here's the issue: Each message might require a different scope of variables. For example, one might require the instance of a `World` object that the `ConnectionListener` doesn't know about (and rightfully shouldn't - the network code should not be coupled to the rest of the program)

So my question is: how can I implement a loosely-coupled system for distributing the reception of network-ignorant messages from a remote connection in my application that somehow magically retains scopes?

EDIT: For comments, example.

Let's assume I have a `World` object. The `World` knows about the entities within it - rocks, trees, you get the general idea. So, a command comes in from the `Remote` saying `:DestroyRock` - which should invoke `World#destroy_rock`. The `World` should not know **where** the command to `:DestroyRock` comes from. It should just know that `World#destroy_rock` was invoked on it.

The issue is, I need some way of finding a middle-man between `ConnectionListener` and `World#destroy_rock`. `ConnectionListener` **definitely** should not be aware of the `World` object, because if it is, that means I've now coupled my **network** code to my **gameplay** logic.. woops. That's pretty bad.

Comment: What do you mean by scopes? Where does the object come from and where do you want it to appear?

Comment: Bad wording, I guess. Long story short I'm asking for an algorithm/method that allows me to keep networking code and the rest of the code completely separate.

Comment: They obviously can't be completely separate, because they need to pass data between themselves. What did you mean by that `World` object? How would the `ConnectionListener` use it if it was allowed to use it?

Comment: Updating OP with example

Comment: Sounds like you need an event framework. The wiring of events can be done in configuration somewhere, outside the realm of either the network code or the objects that actually consume events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ConnectionListener` has to know about the `World` *instance*, because it needs to pass it the command. The `ConnectionListener` is already a middle man, adding another middle man won't solve anything. It should, however, *only know it by interface*. `ICommandable` or something. This would provide a method to pass the message to and return appropriate response, possibly an even to provide asynchronous response/message to client and possibly a filter which messages this object should handle.

Than in the initialization code you'll create the `World` instance and the `ConnectionListener` instance and register the world with the listener. Something like:

```
listener.addCommandable(world);
```

the filter probably makes more sense here than inside the object, so perhaps

```
listener.addCommandable(':DestroyRock', world);
```

(or with a list of commands or something).

I might also make sense to implement the interface not in the `World` object itself, but in an adaptor, so the `World` object does not need to know about the format of the command from network. Especially if there are other ways to send it commands like a stand-alone version that has both user interface and the engine in one process and does not use network.

Of course since Ruby is dynamically typed, an "interface" is just a documented set of methods.

Comment: The issue with `ConnectionListener` knowing about the interface of consumers of these messages is that `ConnectionListener` ends up depending on every consumer of a network event. Interface or not, this isn't very loosely coupled at all. It also doesn't make sense from a programming point of view - Why should the code that is responding to a network event need to know about the intricacies of the server? This violates SRP.

Comment: Also, `ConnectionListener` listens for connection events, such as `Connected`, `Dropped`, `MessageReceived`, `Exception`, etc. It doesn't exist to solely act as a middleman for messaging. Currently it has a dependency on a `MessageDecoder` which decodes the incoming messages, which is then returned back to the `ConnectionListener`, where the `ConnectionListener` has to dispatch the decoded message SOMEHOW.

Comment: @DanPantry: Yes. And it will dispatch it to "Commandable" (or "MessageProcessor" or something). And that can be another middle man, or it can be an interface implemented by the object implementing the logic. Another middle man won't achieve anything here, so it should be interface implemented by the object implementing the logic.

Comment: @DanPantry: Loose coupling does not mean the objects instances don't refer to each other. It means the object instances refer to minimal interfaces.

Comment: I understand that. I thought you meant that I would be directly passing in an instance of World without abstraction into CommandListener :-) which would mean that CommandListener would depend directly on World, rather than an abstractino. I think I will go for an eventbus style system because this is probably not the only event handling I will need. So I will inject an eventbus into CommandListener rather than individual event subscribers.

Comment: @DanPantry: I did say "It should, however, only know it by interface." in the answer.

Comment: Yeah I skipped over that ,selective reading if you will ._.